# POST 400 error on signup - Vue JS / Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do a signup on my app but I'm getting error like:

"POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyCO3QWLiPMJyrZqZLi66vsRsvVVgcGvyQg 400"

I'm using Vue JS and Firebase 9. My code in Signup.vue is:

```
import { initializeApp, db } from "@/firebase.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


const auth = getAuth();

export default {
  name: "signup",
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      country: "",
      city: "",
      zipCode: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    
    signupClick() {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.username, this.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in
          const userProfileData = {
            username: this.username,
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            country: this.country,
            city: this.city,
            zipcode: this.zipCode,
          };

          this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
          console.log("Uspjesna reg");
          const user = userCredential.user;

          
          const userProfile = setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredential.user.uid), userProfileData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: If anyone got this error just UPDATE your rules in Firebase Database. You can see examples here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-web-mobile-client-library#test-mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a weak password. Try confirming this by going to the Network section in the developer tools and click the error name